# how to get all the Currency names which yahoo Finance Currency Converter Supports

Tags: yahoo, yql, yahoo-finance

How can i get all the Currency names or codes which Yahoo finance currency converter supports. i tried using the yahoo Query Language(YQL) with different Select statements but i didnt get.
is there any Yahoo query or is there any other way to get these currency names ? can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [this](http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote) API before to get currency names and codes. Hope it serves your use case.

Comment: But how if the [this](http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote)
URL Changes in future?

Comment: That's the risk with any external API point. There are products which use unofficial google reader API's. There is a risk yes but your code should be robust enough to catch the errors if the endpoint becomes non functional. P.S: Please upvote the answer if it helped you as well :)